# sum of values of variables from tkintet text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python tkinter and I have these data inside tkinter text widget

my question is how I can get total sum of price values

```
No Items        Quantity         Price 

1 beans         1               5.0
2 coffee        1               10.0
3 pizza         2               20.0
                      Total:
```

this my code attempts

```
mysum=0
for line in textt.get("3.0" ,"end"):
    mysum +=float(line)
```

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: @jhpratt yes I edited and added if can help

Comment: Where does the number in the Text come from? Remembering your previous questions I think you're putting it in yourself (so not reading from a file or something like that). It really doesn't make sense to format numbers into text and then parse the text back into numbers to sum up. You should keep all information you need later stored in variables and use the Text widget only as a display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question has nothing to do with tkinter. You are just asking how to parse text. Use the `split` method on every line to split the line into columns.

```
data = textt.get("1.0" ,"end")
lines = data.splitlines()[2:-1] # remove 2 header lines and one footer line
mysum=0
for line in lines:
    price = line.split()[-1] # get the last column
    mysum += float(price) # convert and add
```

You may consider reddit.com/r/learnpython which is a forum more suited for beginner questions.